# inherit type_trait of Derived in CRTP : type of Derived is not complete (yet)

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, crtp

### Library code

My library has a CRTP class `B<Derived>`.
I created a `Trait<T>` class to enable user to change behavior of `B`.
The default setting is `int`.  (`#1`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//B and Trait (library class)
template<class Derived> class B;
template<class T>class Trait{
    public: using type = int;   //<-- default setting    //#1
};   
template<class Derived> class B{
    public: using type = typename Trait<Derived>::type;  //#2
    public: type f(){return 1;}
};
```

### User code ( [**full coliru demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7711d98178a3cf) )

Then, I create a new class `C` with a new setting `std::string`.  (`#3`)
It works fine.

```
//C (user1's class)
template<class Derived> class C ;
template<class Derived>class Trait<C<Derived>>{
    public: using type = std::string;             //#3
};
template<class Derived> class C : public B<Derived>{};
```

Finally, I create a new class `D`.
I want `D` to derive `C`'s setting i.e. `std::string` (not `int`).
However, it is not compilable at `$`.

```
//D (user2's class)
class D : public C<D>{                            //#4
    public: type f(){return "OK";}                //#5
    //$ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'B<D>::type {aka int}' 
};
int main(){
    D dt;
    std::cout<< dt.f() <<std::endl;
}
```

### My understanding

Roughly speaking, here is my understanding about the compile process :-

- Just before `class D` (`#4`), it doesn't know about `D`.
- At `#4`, to identity `D::type`, it looks up `C<D>::type`.
  Finally, it finds that it is defined in `B<D>::type` at `#2`.
- From `#2`, it travels to the definition at `#1` and find `type` = `int`.
  Thus `D::type` = `int`.
- Note that `#3` is **ignored**, because at this point (`#4` and `#5`), `D` is still incomplete.
  The compiler still doesn't fully recognize that `D` is derived from `C<something>` ... yet.

[image]

### **Question**

How to let `D` automatically inherit `Trait`'s setting from `C` without explicitly define another template specialization `Trait<D>`?

In other words, how to make `#3` not ignored for `D`?

`Trait` is probably not a good design (?), but I prefer to let the `type` setting be in a separate trait class.

Answer (score 1):

The instantiating goes like this:

```
D -> C<D> -> B<D> -> Traits<D>
```

`Traits<D>` does not match you partial specialization of `Traits<C<Derived>>`

If you change it to `template<class Derived> class C : public B<C<Derived>>{};` that will in turn instantiate `Traits<C<D>>` and that will match your specialization and you get `std::string` as `type`.

To get the child from `B` you can use.

```
template <typename... T>
struct getChild;

template <template <typename... T> typename First, typename... Rest>
struct getChild<First<Rest...>> { using child = typename getChild<Rest...>::child; };

template <typename First>
struct getChild<First> { using child = First; };
```

and then add in

```
template<class Derived> class B{
    public: using type = typename Trait<Derived>::type;
    using child = typename getChild<Derived>::child;
    public: type f(){return 1;}
};
```

Comment: `B` need `Derived` = the child-most derived class (`D`, not `C`).    This suggestion probably break my existing design.

Comment: B get's instantiated as `B<C<D>>` so it knows about both `C` and `D`. You can easily extract out either one with another helper class.

Comment: In this specific case, it is ok.  However, another user may code `B<E<F<G>>>`.  Another one may simply do `B<H>`.  With this approach, my library need to contain a template utility to extract child-most derived class (`G` and `H`) recursively.  I doubt it is too complex, and not CRTP-intuitive.

Comment: @cppBeginner Updated my answer to show how to get `G` and `H`. See [Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06cd794f05d37995)

Comment: Oh, you go that far.  Thank.  I still feel it is counter CRTP-intuitive + over-engineer.